# How to add items to an array without declaring the array outside a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Let's say I have a 'to-do list' app, and I want to store the IDs of the selected tasks in a variable so I can send them later via `$.ajax` to the server and have them deleted.

What I've always done to achieve this is:

```
var tasks = {
    "ids": []
};

$(document).on('click', '.list > li', function() {

    tasks.ids.push($(this).attr('data-task-id'));

});
```

or

```
var tasks = {
    "ids": []
};

$(document).on('click', '.list > li', function() {

    tasks.ids[tasks['ids'].length] = $(this).attr('data-task-id');

});
```

So I was just curious, can I declare `tasks` inside that callback function, or arrange the code in a ceartain way so I don't need to declare it outside? Otherwise, the array will be reset everytime you click a `<li>`

Comment: Instead of `.attr("data-task-id")` you can use `.data("task-id")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the callback in a closure:

```
$(document).on('click', '.list > li', function() {
  var tasks = { ids: [] };
  return function() {
    tasks.ids[tasks['ids'].length] = $(this).attr('data-task-id');
  };
}()); // <---- NOTE - calling the outer function here
```

There are two anonymous functions: one that gets called immediately and which contains that "tasks" object, and then the other, which is *returned* by the first one. Because the first function is called before the call to the jQuery `.on()` method, what's passed to jQuery is that returned inner function.

The event handler function will retain access to that "tasks" object, so it will "survive" between events.

If that syntax makes you claustrophobic (as it sometimes makes me), you can always split out a separate function:

```
function makeClickHandler() {
    var tasks = { ids: [] };
    return function() {
      tasks.ids[tasks['ids'].length] = $(this).attr('data-task-id');
    };
}

$(document).on( 'click', '.list > li', makeClickHandler() );
```

Comment: Suggestion: `push` the value into the array.

Comment: @bfavaretto oh yes that's a fine idea. Back a long time ago there was actually a slight perf. gain from using the explicit assignment, but I think in modern runtimes it's a wash (and so fast as to be unimportant anyway).

Comment: I didn't know about the performance gain, I *thought* it might be slower for explicitly getting the length. And "claustrophobic" is a really nice way do describe how IIFEs feel sometimes!

Comment: gotcha, is like creating bubbles.. the `tasks` declaration is still 'outside' the code to add the ID

Comment: @bfavaretto i tried that, but for some reason Laravel won't recognize the pushed values

Comment: @bfavaretto even if Laravel had no problem with `push` (maybe i'm doing something wrong there) it wouldn't matter, because the array would get reseted every time you click on a `<li>`

Comment: @johnRivs No, Pointy's code creates just one array, shared by all clicks. And I don't know what's going on with Laravel, `tasks.ids.push(val)` should just work.

Comment: @johnRivs you should post the code you tried or at least double check that you've really copied the suggestions I posted exactly.

Comment: @bfavaretto mm weird, the other day i was `console.log`ing `tasks.ids` and it was returning something like `["138", "139", "140", push: "141"]` and Laravel couldn't recognize the pushed value.. can't remember exactly my code, maybe it was something else acting strange.. Now im using `push` and it works nice, but again, declaring `tasks` outside

Comment: @johnRivs You probably did `tasks.ids.push = $(this).attr('data-task-id')` instead of `tasks.ids.push($(this).attr('data-task-id'))`.

Comment: @johnRivs [Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7j9Vf/) Note that if you need that list *anywhere else* outside of that event handler, then this whole thing becomes, well, a different problem :)

Comment: alright thanks, im gonna stick to declaring `tasks` outside tho, since i'm saying `data: JSON.stringify(tasks)` in a `$.ajax` inside a callback function that happens when i click another button, so i can say `Task::destroy(Input::get('ids'));` in my controller. I guess i could still send a string to laravel and make it work with `destroy` but i'd need `tasks` to be global so i can use it inside another callback function, right?